# Reshaping Dataframe into long format

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, reshape

I have a dataset of the following structure:

```
df

Id    Name          Score
sec1  AI, ML          1
sec2  KI, OL, LP      3
sec3  OM, LI          9
```

I would like to reshape my dataset to get the following structure:

df

```
Id   Name Score
sec1 AI    1
sec1 ML    1
sec2 KI    3
sec2 OL    3
sec2 LP    3
sec3 OM    9
sec3 LI    9
```

To replicate the above example, you can use the df below:

```
df <- data.frame(Id = c("sec1","sec2","sec3"), Name = c( "AI, ML", "KI, OL, LP", "OM, LI"), Score = c(1,3,9))
```

Any Idea would be appreciated!

Comment: `tidyr::separate_rows(df, Name)`

Comment: with `data.table`, you can use `setDT(df)[, strsplit(Name, ","),  by=.(Id, Score)]`